# Change primary key from INT to Guid in production database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a production database which will have to be split into multiple regions. The db has table X which has an int as primary key. Each region will have a table X. The primary keys have to be unique across all regions. We had three ideas to prevent duplicate keys:

1. Create a central index which will distribute unique ints when a new row has to be inserted.
2. Have fixed suffix per region, e.g. int 456 in region '01' will become 45601.
3. Alter the column to use uniqueidentifier instead.

Option 3 seems the best if we didn't already have a production environment. We already have a REST API which is consumed by clients which expect an int as resourceId. We can update those, but that will have to be done gradually. We would have to support both int and uniqueidentifiers for a while.

EDIT:

After reading this link, I'm in doubt between:

https://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/blog/creating-primary-keys-across-databases/

**Bigint** - It seems to be easy to migrate at first, but each database will have a different schema. Adding a new region will require extra attention. Also moving a resource to another region will require to generate a new id.

**Primary Key Pool** - Seems to be the easiest solution and honestly to most fun to implement. Only thing I really have to change is removing the identity and add the query for a new id.

Comment: What about option 4, a `SEQUENCE`?

Comment: The main question I think is, why does adding regions mean that you have to split up a table? Is it a desktop app? If so, is citrix not available? If there is a concern about modifying the existing prod table, then a region child table 1 to 1 to the main table may be easier. Best thing to do usually is that primary keys should be autogenerated numbers while unique keys should be the real world unique keys. That way when you make a change like this, you don't have to worry about all your child row cascades because they are linked to autogenerated numbers or SEQUENCE like @Larnu mentioned.

Comment: Agreed, I question the need for splitting up tables unless they are *really really* massive, like well into the 10s of terabytes, at which point you may need to shard into separate servers anyway

Comment: We have to split the table for business reasons. Our customers sometimes demand their resources are stored in their country. I will have a look at SEQUENCE. As I understand, you are suggestion to add a column which will be globally unique.